# Modify specific cell based on listbox selection

Tags: vba, excel

Need some help with this one:

I have a listbox that i want to be selected and with a button change a cell in a specific cell i mean:

[image]

If i select micifus and click a button it should go to the source cell and change SI for NO

I Found a code that get the number of the entry but haven't got luck trying with vlookup function, any ideas?

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim valor_usd As Integer


    With Me.ListBox1
        For lRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(lRow) Then 
                For lCol = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                    strng = strng & .List(lRow, lCol) & " | "
                Next lCol
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lRow
    End With
    item_select = lbox_por.List(lRow, 0)
    MsgBox item_select
     On Error Resume Next
   valor2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(item_select, Worksheets(4).Range("A2:J19"))
    MsgBox valor2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following line

```
Worksheets(4).Cells(1 + Application.Match(item_select, Worksheets(4).Range("C2:C19"), 0), 9) = "No"
```

Comment: Getting this: "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class” i'm also using the code from a older project i got that works great and still getting this error.

Comment: What happens with Application.Match? You will need to error handle item_select not being present in column C (Assuming that is where you expect to find it?)

Comment: Ok thanks, that worked. All i have to do was add (Val before item_select)